# How to include JRE library in an eclipse project that was cloned from github

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I include the JRE?

The java build path does not give me any options, but the eclipse includes it by default for the projects created locally.[Notice how the build path has no options, but my test project has it included on creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj1aV.png)

Comment: Your Project has been cloned as a general project. Either configure it as a maven project by clicking on project. Or Easiest way is to remove project from workspace and import as a maven project again.

Comment: @NawnitSen seems to work, thanks! any reason why importing it as a maven project includes the libraries?

Comment: @NawnitSen Sorry, I missed your comment. If you want to answer the question, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @howlger no problem sir:)

Comment: @NawnitSen You should earn the reputation points: you were faster and have the simpler solution for this case. So please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Damian Please accept the answer by Nawnit Sen (see my previous comments) so I can delete mine.

Comment: @howlger you are an honest man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Project has been cloned as a general project. Either configure it as a maven project by clicking on project. Or Easiest way is to remove project from workspace and import as a maven project again.